# How to create copper split rings on the top layer (Eagle)

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am just a beginner at using Eagle, nevertheless have spent considerable time trying to figure out how to create double split rings with copper tracks in Eagle. Is there an easy way to do so (image 0 below of what I want to do)?

I have tried the following methods, to no avail.

1. Using the circle tool - cannot edit the circle to form the split with polygon cutout or tRestict and cannot assign signal name. The circle is treated as an uneditable shape.
2. Creating circles with the polygon tool - I created a circle with the polygon tool by alternating between wire bend style 0 and 4 and making the polygon solid. I then did the same with a polygon circle of smaller radius and set it to cutout polygon. The problem with this is that I cannot place my smaller split ring within the cutout region of the inner larger split ring.
3. Using the arc tool - I could make the shape of the ring, except when I try to cut out the split it behaves the same as the circle - it is uneditable (polygon cutout & tRestrict rectangle do not react with the arc).
4. Single solid polygon, using tRestrict - this is the closest I've come to as a solution, where I use circles in tRestrict to cut out the spaces between the solid rings. Problem is, the boundaries of tRestrict form really jagged edges, and I need it to be smooth (as it is a resonator).

I have spent far too long trying to figure this out and am currently at a mental block. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: What I want to create]

Link to images showing different attempts in eagle described above:

[Attempts in Eagle: Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkpBr.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shapes like that are too difficult to produce in Eagle. Draw it in some other CAD program (I can prolly do it in FreeCAD in 5 minutes), make an image and export this image into Eagle. Not sure whether you could give it the signal name though; perhaps, you could try on some random image first.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by importing into Eagle a .dxf file created in AutoCAD via the command "run import-dxf-1_6" after downloading the UDP file import-dxf-1_6 and placing it in the UDP folder found in directory containing eagle.